# Inventory Validation remove inactive stock items

Tags: acumatica

I am tring to add in a extra Where cluse to the INItemList view on the Inventory validation screen.
I only want Active stock items to be validated

if i override the  PXFilteredProcessingJoin view it works but it doent look like it executes the protected virtual IEnumerable initemlist() on Base lvl and all the stock shows even if the warhouse arent selected:

```
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<InventoryItem, INSiteFilter,
        LeftJoin<INSiteStatusSummary,
            On<INSiteStatusSummary.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
            And<INSiteStatusSummary.siteID, Equal<Current<INSiteFilter.siteID>>>>>,
        Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>,
            And<InventoryItem.isTemplate, Equal<False>,
            And<InventoryItem.itemStatus, Equal<InventoryItemStatus.active>>>>,
        OrderBy<
            Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>
        INItemList;
```

[image]

I have also tried overiding the IEnumerable but this made the screen very slow and added a extra 8 seconds to the load time:

```
    protected virtual IEnumerable initemlist()
    {
        INSiteFilter iNSiteFilter = Base.Filter.Current;
        INSiteFilterExt iNSiteFilterExt = iNSiteFilter.GetExtension<INSiteFilterExt>();

        var list = new ArrayList();

        foreach (var item in Base.INItemList.Select())
        {
            if (iNSiteFilterExt.UsrOnlyActive == true)
            {
                InventoryItem inventoryItem = item;

                if (inventoryItem.ItemStatus == "AC")
                {
                  //  yield return item;
                    list.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
              //  yield return item;
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Lastly i have tried adding a extra WhereAnd in INSiteFilter_RowSelected but this doent seem to work. I dont think I am doing this correctly

```
  protected virtual void INSiteFilter_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
  {
     Base.INItemList.WhereAnd<Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, Equal<InventoryItemStatus.active>>>();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a modified version of Sergeys code found in this article I got the functionality working:
https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/06/using-pxview-in-dataview-delegate.html

Here is my DAC:

```
namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    // Acuminator disable once PX1011 InheritanceFromPXCacheExtension [Justification]
    public class INSiteFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INSiteFilter>
    {
        #region UsrOnlyActive
        [PXBool]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Only Active")]

        public virtual bool? UsrOnlyActive { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrOnlyActive : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrOnlyActive> { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

But more important the paging on the page:

```
 // Need to expose the view to the GraphExtension
 [PXFilterable]
        public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<InventoryItem,
            INSiteFilter,
            LeftJoin<INSiteStatusSummary, On<INSiteStatusSummary.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
             And<INSiteStatusSummary.siteID, Equal<Current<INSiteFilter.siteID>>>>>,
            Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>, And<InventoryItem.isTemplate, Equal<False>>>,
            OrderBy<Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>
        INItemList;


        protected virtual IEnumerable initemlist()
        {


            // This magic gets the first page(20 in my case) records in the view and records 20 to 40 when going to the next page

            PXView select = new PXView(this.Base, true, INItemList.View.BqlSelect);

            Int32 totalrow = 0;
            Int32 startrow = PXView.StartRow;
            List<object> result = select.Select(PXView.Currents, PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches,
                PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startrow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalrow);

            PXView.StartRow = 0;

            INSiteFilter filter = Base.Filter.Current;
            INSiteFilterExt filterExt = filter.GetExtension<INSiteFilterExt>();


                       if (filterExt.UsrOnlyActive == true)
        {
            //Because I am removing items in the foreach loop I cant remove  the item from the result list else there will be a error so I made a 2de list
            List<object> result2 = result;
            foreach (PXResult<InventoryItem, INSiteStatusSummary> item in result)
            {
                var inventoryItem = (InventoryItem)item;

                if (inventoryItem.ItemStatus != "AC")
                {
                    result2.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            return result2;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of making a copy of the parent data set and then removing all the records that don't match your criteria it would be more efficient to yield return within your IF.

Comment: I like that idea then I can use this pattern on a lot more screens ill test and then update when completed

Comment: i added in the yield return item but it stops working when I tick the only active box. it only shows a hand full of items and you cant go to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to redeclare both the view and view delegate in your `GraphExtension`. Within your view delegate call the select to the Base view. This restricts the data records being iterated through by your `IEnumerable initemlist()` by the restrictions in the Base level. The additional restrictions within your declared view delegate will then be applied and return to the page.

The timing issue may have been because you are yield returning records but also adding them to a list return at the end of the IEnumerable.

```
public class INIntegrityCheckExtension : PXGraphExtension<INIntegrityCheck>
    {
        [PXFilterable]
        public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<InventoryItem,
    INSiteFilter,
    LeftJoin<INSiteStatusSummary, On<INSiteStatusSummary.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>,
        And<INSiteStatusSummary.siteID, Equal<Current<INSiteFilter.siteID>>>>>,
    Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>, And<InventoryItem.isTemplate, Equal<False>>>,
    OrderBy<Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>
    INItemList;

        protected virtual IEnumerable initemlist()
        {
            INSiteFilter filter = Base.Filter.Current;
            INSiteFilterExtension filterExt = filter.GetExtension<INSiteFilterExtension>();

            foreach (InventoryItem item in Base.INItemList.Select())
            {
                if (filterExt.UsrOnlyActive == true)
                {
                    if (item.ItemStatus == "AC")
                    {
                        yield return item;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Joshua This is how to code is currently running at the client. The moment you add the IEnumerable to the GraphExtension the speed issues start

Comment: To confirm you have BOTH the view and the IEnumerable declared on the client? I got the time increase if it was only 1 but had "regular" time when implemented as in my example.

Comment: Yes, I even copied your answer to my project to test and just changed 'filterExt.UsrOnlyActive == true' to 'true==true for testing'

Comment: How many Inventory Items are to be returned? I want to test locally with a comparable data set to see if I can replicate your issue.

Comment: The system has 28103 stock items

Comment: Got it working with this article:  https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/06/using-pxview-in-dataview-delegate.html . It was the amount of records being processed

Comment: Did you modify the BQL select statement to filter by active or did you just do a value check on the return as in our examples? Either way you should post the final working code as an answer ( with explanation! ) so it may be marked and upvoted.

Comment: Okay ill add it in now :)

Comment: i kept the original View and could just add in my logic